# Present a UIView over a view

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios

How can I make a custom view in iOS which appears above the existing view,but smaller? It should be like UIAlertView, but taken from a .xib file. After user taps a certain button, the small view vanishes and the normal view appears.

If this is posiible, how can I do it? And.. if it's not hard for you, please, include code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a modal view.  Modal views make it easy to have a view take over the screen for a little while, then when they get dismissed have the background view resume where it left off without having to worry about who's on top or handling events in partially-obscured views.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) is Apple's article describing it.

They key is to have the controller class for your view call `[self presentModalViewController:popupController animated:YES];` where "popupController" is the view controller for the view you want to show up.  When you're ready to make it go away, call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];`

Answer (score -2):

You can just use the `addSubview:` method on your `UIWindow` or your visible `UIViewController`'s view to show the `UIView`, and you can hide/remove it later by calling `removeFromSuperview` on the presented `UIView`.

Comment: How should I do it? Should I create a separate .nib? And what's the code I shall write? I'm writing AppViewController *subView = [[AppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubVIEW" bundle:nil];
  [self.view insertSubview:subView.view atIndex:0]; where SubVIEW is a separate .xib.